# subsection head runin in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to do `runin` the `subsection` text in `TOC` with a `square bullet` separator, e.g.,

[image]

For this, I've tried with:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\definecolor{newmuddydkyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}
\def\smyellowsquare{\leavevmode\raise.3ex\hbox{\color{newmuddydkyellow}\vrule
width 3pt height 3pt depth0pt}}
\def\subsecsepbullet{\nobreak\ignorespaces\hskip4\p@\ignorespaces\nobreak\smyellowsquare\nobreak\ignorespaces\hskip4\p@\ignorespaces\nobreak}%
\renewcommand\l@subsection[2]{\bgroup%
\def\numberline##1{\relax}%
\raggedright\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont%
{\it\raggedright#1\ignorespaces\hspace{9\p@}\ignorespaces#2}\subsecsepbullet%
\egroup}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\chapter{Chapter Head}

\section{First level head1}
\subsection{Second level head1}
\subsection{Second level head2}
\subsection{Second level head3}
\subsection{Second level head4}
\subsection{Second level head5}
\section{First level head2}
\end{document}
```

Which produced the output as:

[image]

Please advise how to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the package `titletoc`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}


%******************************* added <<<<<<
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsection}[3.8em]% 3.8em default indent for latex book
{\itshape}{}{}
{\hspace{1.5ex}\thecontentspage}
[\quad\smyellowsquare\quad][]
%*******************************

\makeatletter
\definecolor{newmuddydkyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}
\def\smyellowsquare{\leavevmode\raise.3ex\hbox{\color{newmuddydkyellow}\vrule
        width 3pt height 3pt depth0pt}}
\def\subsecsepbullet{\nobreak\ignorespaces\hskip4\p@\ignorespaces\nobreak\smyellowsquare\nobreak\ignorespaces\hskip4\p@\ignorespaces\nobreak}%
\makeatother

 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \chapter{Chapter Head}
    
    \section{First level head1}
    \subsection{Second level head1}
    \subsection{Second level head2}
    \subsection{Second level head3}
    \subsection{Second level head4}
    \subsection{Second level head5}
    \section{First level head2}
\end{document}
```

The starred version of the command groups the entries in a single paragraph.

```
\titlecontents*{⟨section⟩}[⟨left-margin⟩]
{⟨above-code⟩}{⟨numbered-entry-format⟩}{⟨numberless-entry-format⟩}
{⟨filler-page-format⟩}[⟨separator⟩]
```

Comment: Thanks, its working great